# .NET Core Debugging stopped working in Visual studio Code 1.9

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I've updated to visual studio code 1.9 and suddenly I can't debug my .NET Core Application. If I look into the launch.json it says the "type: coreclr" is not accepted. Does anyone know what's different what do I need to change? I've left my config file below.

Thanks in advance :-)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp1.1\\BUnity.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command.pickProcess}"
        },
         {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp1.1\\BUnity.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I desinstalled the C# Extension. It's required to debug .NET Core applications